# Why does my Rcpp function sometimes return NaN and other times the correct answer for the same inputs?

Tags: c++, r, matrix, rcpp, matrix-multiplication

I am writing an Rcpp function to multiply a banded matrix by a vector. I have an R wrapper function that makes it easier to call the C++ function. I get the same issue regardless of whether I run the C++ function directly or through the R wrapper function

```
#library(Rcpp)
##########params#############
#p: lower bandwidth
#q: upper bandwidth
#A: data matrix of size n*m
#x: vector to multiply by
#n: number of rows
#m: number of columns
  
  
cppFunction("NumericVector bandMatVecMult(int p, int q, NumericMatrix A, NumericVector x, 
int n, int m) {
  NumericVector prods (n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int istart = std::max(0, std::min(i - p, m - 1));
    int istop = std::min(m, i + q);
    
    NumericVector Arow = A(i, _);
    Arow = Arow[Range(istart, istop)];
    NumericVector b = x[Range(istart, istop)];
    prods[i] = std::inner_product(Arow.begin(), Arow.end(), b.begin(), 0.0);
    //NumericVector prodsVec = Arow * b;
    //prods[i] = sum(prodsVec);
  }
  return prods;
}")
bandMatVecMultR = function(l.bandwidth, u.bandwidth, mat, vec = 1:dim(mat)[2]){
  dim.mat = dim(mat)
  
  result = bandMatVecMult(p = as.integer(l.bandwidth), 
                          q = as.integer(u.bandwidth), 
                          A = as.matrix(mat), 
                          x = vec, 
                          n = as.integer(dim.mat[1]), 
                          m = as.integer(dim.mat[2]))
  
  return(result)
}
```

I run the code on the same input 100 times to show my issue.

```
for (i in 1:100){
  a = bandMatVecMultR(81, 0, y, vec = 1:10)
  print(a)
}
```

Sometimes I get the correct answer, other times something else. Again, the input stays constant. The issue persists whether I use the inner_product function or calculate dot product myself

```
#a correct output
[1]  1  1  2  2  5  4  3  3  3  3  6  6  5  4  4  4  4  4  4 10 12  8 10 11  9  5  5  5  5  5 11  9
 [33]  7  8  9  7  7  6  6  6 17 14 12 12  9 12  7  7  7  7 27 25 23 16 15  9 12 10 18 20 12 14 13 14
 [65] 17 15 19 16 13 10 13 10 10  9  9 38 26 25 20 20 19 21 18 17 18 19 10 10 10 10 10  0  0  0  0  0
 [97]  0  0  0  0

#an output with random NaN
[1]   1   1   2   2   5   4   3   3   3   3 NaN   6   5   4 NaN   4   4   4   4  10  12   8  10  11
 [25]   9   5   5   5   5   5  11   9   7   8   9   7 NaN   6   6   6 NaN  14  12  12 NaN  12   7   7
 [49]   7 NaN  27  25  23  16  15   9  12  10 NaN  20  12  14  13  14  17  15  19  16  13 NaN  13  10
 [73]  10   9   9  38  26  25  20  20  19  21  18  17  18  19  10  10  10  10  10   0   0   0   0 NaN
 [97]   0   0   0   0

#NaN and different formatting
[1]  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  2.000000e+00  2.000000e+00  5.000000e+00  4.000000e+00
  [7]  3.000000e+00  3.000000e+00  3.000000e+00  3.000000e+00  6.000000e+00  6.000000e+00
 [13]  5.000000e+00  4.000000e+00  4.000000e+00  4.000000e+00  4.000000e+00  4.000000e+00
 [19]  4.000000e+00           NaN  1.200000e+01  8.000000e+00  1.000000e+01  1.100000e+01
 [25]  9.000000e+00  5.000000e+00  5.000000e+00  5.000000e+00  5.000000e+00  5.000000e+00
 [31]  1.100000e+01  9.000000e+00  7.000000e+00  8.000000e+00  9.000000e+00  7.000000e+00
 [37]  7.000000e+00  6.000000e+00  6.000000e+00  6.000000e+00  1.700000e+01  1.400000e+01
 [43]  1.200000e+01  1.200000e+01  9.000000e+00  1.200000e+01  7.000000e+00  7.000000e+00
 [49]  7.000000e+00  7.000000e+00  2.700000e+01  2.500000e+01  2.300000e+01  1.600000e+01
 [55]  1.500000e+01  9.000000e+00  1.200000e+01  1.000000e+01  1.800000e+01  2.000000e+01
 [61]  1.200000e+01  1.400000e+01  1.300000e+01  1.400000e+01  1.700000e+01  1.500000e+01
 [67]  1.900000e+01  1.600000e+01  1.300000e+01  1.000000e+01  1.300000e+01  1.000000e+01
 [73]  1.000000e+01  9.000000e+00  9.000000e+00  3.800000e+01  2.600000e+01  2.500000e+01
 [79]  2.000000e+01  2.000000e+01  1.900000e+01  2.100000e+01  1.800000e+01  1.700000e+01
 [85]  1.800000e+01  1.900000e+01  1.000000e+01  1.000000e+01  1.000000e+01  1.000000e+01
 [91]  1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00 1.671951e-131  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
 [97]  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
```

I get this error for larger matrices (1000 x 10), but I haven't been able to reproduce it for smaller matrices (10 x 10). I have custom code that turns a matrix into banded form, and my regular computations work fine on it (y %*% vec works fine). In addition, I have a version of this function that multiplies a matrix by vector without the banded assumption, and it does not produce this error.

```
cppFunction("NumericVector matVecMult(NumericMatrix A, NumericVector x, 
int n, int m) {
  NumericVector prods(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    NumericVector Arow = A(i, _);
    prods[i] = std::inner_product(Arow.begin(), Arow.end(), x.begin(), 0.0);
  }
  return prods;
}")

matVecMultR = function(mat, vec = 1:dim(mat)[2]){
  dim.mat = dim(mat)
  
  result = matVecMult(A = as.matrix(mat), 
                      x = vec, 
                      n = as.integer(dim.mat[1]), 
                      m = as.integer(dim.mat[2]))
  
  return(result)
}
```

I just started using Rcpp yesterday and haven't written C++ code until yesterday. What is causing the issue, and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you confirmed that the C++ code works as intended when executed without involving `R` with the same data?

Comment: Second the debugging tip: check all your intermediary results.  Also, while `Rcpp` does have `NumericVector` and `NumericMatrix` these are _not_ really meant or tuned for linear algebra. Look into `RcppArmadillo` which is as easy to use from R, but relies on `Armadillo` which, if memory serves, even has banded matrices (though we interface only full ones).  And then there is `RcppEigen` too.

Comment: Finding a `NaN` in well-understood calculations usually means you've used undefined memory somewhere.  Use your favorite debugging tool to figure out where that is, or dump all of your intermediate results and analyze them, or something similar.

Depending on your processor, you may also be able to set its floating point status word to automatically signal when a calculation is done involving a `NaN`.  This could get you closer to the problem.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I'll keep this advice in mind as a continue learning C++. I actually found the issue was this line: int istop = std::min(m, i + q);
It should be int istop = std::min(m - 1, i + q);

I just realized that the ending index used by the Range function is inclusive like in R, rather than exclusive like in other languages